# clickhouse tabix max execution time in setting

Tags: clickhouse

when i create profile
in users.xml
and append this profile to a new user (web-user) in users.xml

```
 <web>
    <max_execution_time>5</max_execution_time>
    <readonly>1</readonly> 
 </web>
```

after I restart clickhouse server,
and I enter to tabix with default user also the max execution time in tabix is change to 5 seconds,
is this a bug ?
why this happend?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart CH. Users settings are applied without restart.

Tabbix has own settings and they override yours

[image]